Imagick causing images to become larger
I have a javascript canvas that I convert to blob using image/webp and a quality of 0.25.
This canvas blob is then posted to my php which loads the image into Imagick and does virtually nothing (so far), but the image goes from 269Kb to 357Kb in size - what is happening here and how can I prevent this?
js
mycanvas.convertToBlob({type: 'image/webp', quality: 0.25}).then(resultBlob => {
     sendImage(resultBlob, file.name);
     resolve(); 
}).catch(error => {
     reject(error); 
});

php
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA, 90000000);
$imagick->readImageBlob($blob);
if ( $imagick->getImageFormat()!='WEBP' ) $imagick->setImageFormat('webp');
$tblob = $imagick->getImageBlob();
$size = strlen($tblob);


Do you really intend to write: $imagick->getImageFormat()!='web'? Shouldn't that be: $imagick->getImageFormat()!='webp'?

... thanks ... but same problem (file grows)

What happens if you change the second parameter of $imagick->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA, 90000000); to some other number? How is it affecting the image size?

... setResourceLimit settings does not affect the resulting image

One of the possiblities is that your original webp is compressed , but after you process the data thru PHP (imagick) it is not. (at least I do not see any statement in your code like $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality($quality); // 90,80,70  ) -- For this, you may refer to official documentation

Wouldn't compressing a compressed file cause double-compression (i.e. more blurring)?
